# Q: Issue finding the nearest street segment(s) based on an x,y coordinate and ordering by distance

Tags: st-intersects, st-distance

I'm trying to pull the SNOW_ROUTE attribute from the nearest street segments based on an X,Y coordinate and order the results by nearest segment.  I'm able to return the snow route information but the distance values are not returning and the results are not returned in order with the nearest at the top.

Here is the query that returns the snow routes but doesn't return distance values or sorted by nearest:

```
SELECT SNOW_ROUTE, sde.st_distance(shape,SDE.ST_POINT(1362521.32365368, 451903.559144756, 300004)) DISTANCE
FROM SDE.STREETS
WHERE sde.st_intersects(shape, sde.st_buffer(SDE.ST_POINT(1362521.32365368, 451903.559144756, 300004),200)) = 1
ORDER BY DISTANCE;


SNOW_ROUTE   DISTANCE
---------- ----------
2-13R                
2-13R                
2-12P                
2-12P                
2-12P                

5 rows selected.
```

This is another attempt that runs without error but no rows are selected:

```
SELECT SNOW_ROUTE, sde.st_distance(shape,SDE.ST_POINT(1362521.32365368, 451903.559144756, 300004)) DISTANCE
FROM SDE.STREETS
WHERE sde.st_intersects(shape, sde.st_buffer(SDE.ST_POINT(1362521.32365368, 451903.559144756, 300004),500)) = 1
and  sde.st_distance(sde.st_geometry(1362521.32365368, 451903.559144756,null,null, 300004),shape) < 500
ORDER BY distance;
```

Comment: Is the SRID good /represented in your database?  select * from sde.st_coordinate_systems where ID in (3857,300004);  etc

Comment: Thanks, cm1.  The SRID was the issue.  I opened the SDE.ST_SPATIAL_REFERENCES table and found the correct SRID.  Distances are now returning.

Comment: Glad to hear it Ken and welcome to Geographic Information Systems StackExchange. If you found my comment useful, you can click the small red up-arrow next to my comment to indicate it was useful.

Comment: <-- (about here) You have to 'hover' your mouse cursor just to the left of the comment and the arrows appear : ) Thanks Ken

Comment: It may be a popup blocker squashing it. No worries, glad to help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Is the SRID good /represented in your database? select * from sde.st_coordinate_systems where ID in (3857,300004); etc – cm1"